# Dashboard for my car

Tags: dashboard, car

I am looking for a dashboard (template) I can customize to display stats from my car. I mounted an iPad in my car and need to show some data in real-time.

Design should be nice and modern with: gauges, diagrams, maps and a small calendar. 
I really only need a HTML (node.js app to run on in-car-raspi) template, but it's very hard to find the matching one.

Comment: What kins of input? Raw CANbus data, over a wire? Maybe BlueTooth?  How does the data get into the dashboard, and what does the data look like?